# How do I fix multiple redirect in blogger

Tags: blogger

I'm using blogger blog with costome domain, with that cloudflare also, but the Google page insight say avoid multiple redirect

I knows it's because my website makes http request and https, I made all settings throug cloudflare like always use HTTPS, rewrite https and also try forwarding to https via page rule in cloudflare

But still it didn't do anything at all, my whole concern is I'm trying to boost my page speed.

But I don't know how I can solve this problem, please any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Using internal https from blogger, maybe can help,
here...I'm not using external https forwarding

and You can do this
[image: NO FORWARDING HTTPS]

So, if user want to visit on your page using http, they can do that..
if user want to visit using https, they can do that.